# Word VBA "Label Not Defined" If Bookmark exists command

Tags: vba, ms-word, exists, bookmarks

I am very new to VBA and just learning. Here's my situation and problem:

1) I created a working userform with text and comboboxes linking to bookmarks
2) Problem is that it doesn't work if some bookmarks don't exist (and the project will require this: the form will need to run on documents where not all bookmarks are present)
3) I would like the form stop giving me error messages if bookmarks arent there and just fill out the ones that are existing in that particular ocument
4) Here's the Code:

```
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveDocument
          If .Bookmarks.Exists("cboYourName") Then
        .Range.Text = cboYourName.Value
        Else: GoTo 28
    End If
         If .Bookmarks.Exists("cboYourPhone") Then
         .Range.Text = cboYourPhone.Value
         Else: GoTo 32
    End If
        If .Bookmarks.Exists("cboYourFax") Then
        .Range.Text = cboYourFax.Value
        Else: GoTo 36
    End If
         If .Bookmarks.Exists("cboYourEmail") Then
         .Range.Text = cboYourEmail.Value
        Else: GoTo 40
    End If
         If .Bookmarks.Exists("txtContractName") Then
         .Range.Text = txtContractName.Value
         Else: GoTo 44
    End If
          If .Bookmarks.Exists("txtContractNumber") Then
          .Range.Text = txtContractNumber.Value
          Else: End
    End If
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

4) How do I get this to work?????????

Answer (score 0):

I think you're close. First, avoid Goto statements. In your code, it's hard to tell what you mean to do. I think the errors are from the Goto statements. Its parameter is a label, not a line number. Second, avoid using End. It's better to have a closing routine. That said, the code works with any number of Exists statements.

```
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveDocument
        If .Bookmarks.Exists("cboYourName") Then
            .Range.Text = "cboYourName text."
        Else
            Debug.Print "Bookmark exists."
        End If

        If .Bookmarks.Exists("cboYourPhone") Then
           .Range.Text = "cboYourPhone text"
        Else
            Debug.Print "Bookmark does not exists."
        End If
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

However, be aware that each found bookmark completely replaces the content of the document, including subsequently found bookmarks. Is that what you mean to do?